# Poner valor por defecto a propiedad en GRAPHQL

Tags: sql, nodejs, base-de-datos, api, graphql

Estoy intentando poner un valor por defecto a la propiedad "role" del UserType de mi app con graphql y express.
He intentado varias formas pero ninguna parece tener lógica y no me ha funcionado, me gustaría poner un valor por defecto a esa propiedad porque cuando un usuario se registre la idea es que tenga un role "básico".

Dejo por aquí mi código:

````
  name: "User",
  description: "User type",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    username: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    displayName: { type: GraphQLString },
    phone: { type: GraphQLString },
    role: { type:  GraphQLString}
  }),
});```
````

Comment: Parece que debe haber una operación mutation  donde se hace el set de un nuevo usuario, ahi es donde se podría pasar el valor por defecto "básico" hacia la base de datos; porque en el esquema de GraphQL solo se definen los tipos para cada field (la pieza de código que compartes), no se asignan valores.